# Android : How to set a current tab selected by clicking on each different button?

Tags: android, tabs

I have an app in which i have three buttons in the first page(For example say A, B, C buttons). When i click on any one of these three buttons they will navigate to same tabActivity page. By default first tab is getting selected. But what i want is, when i click on A button first tab should be get selected. when i click on B button second tab should be get selected. when i click on C button third tab should get selected. I dont know how to do this. Can any one help me on this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: i have made changes in user's answer the probelm is in last he has set tabhost.setcurrenttab(2) which default goes to second tab either instead of 2 u can use 1 or remove that line this both works for u

Answer (score 2):

Try This,

on clicking button A

```
tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

on clicking button B

```
tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
```

on clicking button C

```
tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

in your activity class try this and in my app is working just fine.

```
Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab 
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

            // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused) 
           intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ArtistsActivity.class);
            // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artists",
                              res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                          .setContent(intent);
            tabHost.addTab(spec);

            // Do the same for the other tabs 
           intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AlbumsActivity.class); 
           spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("albums").setIndicator("Albums", 
                             res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_albums))
                          .setContent(intent);
            tabHost.addTab(spec);

            intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SongsActivity.class);
            spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("songs").setIndicator("Songs",
                              res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_songs)).setContent(intent);
            tabHost.addTab(spec);   
        }
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Hi, with the above code the second tab gets selected by default. But my requiremnet is different. I want second tab selected only when i click on the "B" button in first page. Third tab should get selected only when i click on the "c" button in first page.

Comment: Just cut and paste this tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);  to the INTENT where you want the tab to be default